# How to iterate over the rows of a 2D ndarray to find if each row contains a particular value

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have some code which does the basics of what I need, basically it increments a count each time a row in a 2D ndarray contains a zero. I was wondering if there was a more pythonic way to do this than the count method, or to have the row indices as well?

**Code**

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 0, 3], [4, 0, 4]])

count = 0
for row in arr:
    if 0 in row:
        print("yes there is a zero")
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: `(arr == 0).any(axis=1).sum()`.

Comment: Hi Quang, if you put that as an answer I'll happily accept it, thank you.